# if (isset($_POST["Name"]==null $_POST["Email"]==null, $_POST["Password"]==null, $_POST["Phone"]==null)) what is wrong with this in php

Tags: php, database, authentication, null, isset

i have a database and want to check if the elements are set or not before they pass to database because i dont want to pass null values for entities mentioned but while using this statement i find out values are passing without being check for availability.

i tried to pass those elements to the database but check for nulls first and they were not checked for nulls and sometimes got this error as well:

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you
> can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs....on line
> 3

Comment: `isset` will accept multiple arguments and return false if any value returns a false / empty type value. ie: `if( isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'] ) ){}` etc

Answer (score 0):

The isset function works differently, you need to put a variable into it, not a condition.

For example:

```php
$arr = [
  'a' => 'Hello',
];

$bool = isset($arr['a']) // return true
$bool = isset($arr['b']) // return false
```

this page [detailed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

---

Let's try writing the following to fix the error in your code.

```php
if (
  !isset($_POST["Name"]) ||
  !isset($_POST["Email"]) ||
  !isset($_POST["Password"]) ||
  !isset($_POST["Phone"])
) {
  // some fields is null, not valid.
}
```

or

```php
if (!isset($_POST["Name"], $_POST["Email"], $_POST["Password"], $_POST["Phone"])) {
  // some fields is null, not valid.
}
```

Comment: @Rezwansafi If the answer is satisfactory, you can confirm and accept. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent `null` values from being inserted into the DB:

```sql
CREATE TABLE User(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

also, use the **required** attribute in your html document:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php"> 
    <input type="text" id="username" required>  
</form>
```